# How to stick a div on a background image?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a header that has a background image. On this image I would like to place some divs with circle shapes to add some animations. The problem is that once the view port shrinks, the shapes will move accordingly if absolute position is used. I've tried it out with vh and vw units but the shapes will still move even if the background photo won't change too much. I just want that div to be there as if it was part of the photo. Is this possible?  [image]

Comment: its better to remove the design from the image, and then it doesnt matter if its a few px off

Comment: Use some math. If the image size is changed, then deduct the position basing on this size

Answer (score 0):

There are is a pretty neat hack you can do for circles (or perfect squares). In an `:after` pseudo-class, you can say padding-bottom: 100% - this percent is relative to the `.circle` itself, and thus the width and height are exactly the same. Coupled with a percentage on the width of the circle, you can make these resize with the container.

You'll notice that resizing the container keeps the size of the circle relative to the parent, and the position relative to the parent as well.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}

.circle {
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle.top-left {
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}

.circle.bottom-right {
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="circle top-left"></div>
  <div class="circle bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```